# Initialize entire drive realtime model from string?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

I want to serialize all of the data in my realtime document to a string with which I can later initialize a new realtime document.  I want to do this so my users can make copies of their drive files, save different versions, etc, and I can re-initialize the relevant realtime documents from the string.

I see I can call `document.getModel().getRoot().toString()` to get a string representation of the root CollaborativeMap, but I don't see any easy way to load that string back IN to a CollaborativeMap.  Also, the string returned is not JSON, so I can't easily use JSON.parse to turn it back into a normal JS object and iterate from there.

I can make this work by hand.  Is there any easy automated way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that on the service side using the realtime.get() and update() methods:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime

Comment: wow, that looks perfect, thanks.  Wish I found out about this a few days ago ;)